# optional many to one or zero issue in Entity Framework

Tags: sql-server, database, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, code-first

I am trying to create a quick demo shop, and I am failing with an `optional many to one or zero` relationship.

The relevant classes are:

1. Item

   ```
   public class Item
   {
       public int ID { get; set; }
       public string Name { get; set; }
       public int SubCategoryID { get; set; }
       public virtual SubCategory Category { get; set; }
       public double Price { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. Order

   ```
   public class Order
   {
       public int ID { get; set; }
       public DateTime DateOfOrder { get; set; }
       public virtual ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
       public int CustomerID { get; set; }
       public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
   }
   ```

However, I am getting confused because viewing the model shows:

[image]

but, the database itself shows (for items):

[image]

Which indicates to me that each item can only belong to a single order.

Do I have to create a separate class that is many to many orders/items?

I seem to remember EF doing this automatically, but, I haven't touched it for a few years and I just can't remember what I used to do.

Comment: I thought this will be very straight forward, but, I have tried copying various examples from here and I just don't seem to be having much luck...

Answer (score 0):

I had to add:

```
public virtual ICollection<order> Orders { get; set; }
```

to the Item... I'm never going to call it this way, but it looks like that is required for EF to build this relationship.

I am sure it used to be easier, so, leaving this question open so someone can give a better answer!

Comment: if you don't want an "Orders" property, you could also use [fluent api](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620.aspx#ManyToMany) to configure the relationship: `modelBuilder.Entity<Order>().HasMany(t => t.Items).WithMany()`

Answer (score 0):

If you add a collection of `Orders` to the `Item` entity, EF will create for you implicitly the [junction table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table) on your DB. In this [page](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx) you can find more info about how to configure a many to many relationship.

The junction table generally is mapped when you need to add an additional column (that excludes both keys of the tables you are joining). In that case you need to create two one-to-many relationships between the entity that represent the junction table and `Order` and `Item` respectively. Some people recommend always map the junction table because that way you have all the tables represented as entities and you can write queries starting by the junction table. You can find interesting info about this subject in this [link](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2014/03/12/avoid-many-to-many-mappings-in-orms/). But, in my experience, in most cases you can work perfectly without map explicitly the junction table.